# Image gets corrupted after FileUpload with FtpWebRequest

Tags: file-upload, async-await, ftpwebrequest

I have a code that uploads an image. I use `await/async`. The code do upload .txt files and .jpg files for example.

However, when uploading a .jpg image. It does get uploaded. However when I download it from the server manually to my desktop(using FileZilla), I can't open the file in paint. I get this error:
***Paint cannot read this file. This is not a valid bitmap file, or its format is not currently supported***

**Other Information:**
Original Filesize: 109 309 bytes
When Uploaded to server: 109 308 bytes

```js
 void uploadimage()
        {
            String sourceimage = "C:/ESD/image_2.jpg";
            Task<bool> task = FtpUploadFile(sourceimage);
            if (task.IsFaulted == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(task.Result.ToString());
            }
        }
        private Task closeRequestStreamAsync(Stream requestStream) { return Task.Run(() => { requestStream.Close(); }); }
        public async Task<bool> FtpUploadFile(string filename)
        {
            //if exception occurs we want to be able to close these
            FtpWebResponse response = null;
            FtpWebRequest request = null;
            FileStream sourceStream = null;
            Stream requestStream = null;
            try
            {
                bool isimage = false; String ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
                if (ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".jpeg" || ext == ".png" || ext == ".gif" || ext == ".bmp") { isimage = true; }

                request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://someurl.com/Folder1/test1.jpg");
                request.UsePassive = true;
                if (isimage == true) { request.UseBinary = true; } //for images
                if (isimage == false) { request.UseBinary = false; } //for text
                request.KeepAlive = true; //keep the connection open
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                request.ConnectionGroupName = "Group1";
                request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 4;

                //These are the credentials.
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");


                sourceStream = File.OpenRead(filename);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[sourceStream.Length];
                await sourceStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                sourceStream.Close();

                requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
                await requestStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                //MPM  This is the call that takes the time     
                await closeRequestStreamAsync(requestStream);

                //response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                WebResponse responseWeb = await request.GetResponseAsync();
                response = (FtpWebResponse)responseWeb;
                if (response.StatusDescription.Contains("226"))
                {
                    //This means that we successfully have uploaded the file!
                }
                response.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errMSG = string.Format("Upload File failed, exception: {0}", ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: "It does get uploaded." How are you checking this? Are you opening the file on the server and it shows the correct image? Are you checking the correct file size? Are you just seeing the code "works"?

Comment: `response.StatusDescription.Contains("226")` tells it is uploaded. Then I check visually in FileZilla that the file is there. But the file is corrupted somehow. I cant open it from server or download it to desktop and opening it in paint for example.

Answer (score 0):

I did forget to add this to my code so images do use binary for images. Now it works:

```js
 if (isimage == true) { request.UseBinary = true; } //for images
 if (isimage == false) { request.UseBinary = false; } //for text
```